# Whitespace string can't be replaced with NA in R

Tags: r, dataframe, row, missing-data

I want to substitute whitespaces with NA. A simple way could be `df[df == ""] <- NA`, and that works for most of the cells of my data frame....but not for everyone!

I have the following code:

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

#Read website
htmlpage <- read_html("http://www.soccervista.com/results-Liga_MX_Apertura-2016_2017-844815.html")

#Extract table
df <- htmlpage %>% html_nodes("table") %>% html_table()
df <- as.data.frame(df)

#Set whitespaces into NA's
df[df == ""] <- NA
```

I figured out that some whitespaces have a little whitespace between the quotation marks

`df[11,1]
[1] " "`

So my solution was to do the next: `df[df == " "] <- NA`

However the problem is still there and it has the little whitespace! I thought the trim function would work but it didn't...

```
#Trim
df[,c(1:10)] <- sapply(df[,c(1:10)], trimws)
```

However, the problem can't go off.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need to use `lapply` instead of `sapply` as `sapply` returns a `matrix` instead of a `list` and this can create problems in the quotes.

```
df[1:10] <- lapply(df[1:10], trimws)
```

and another option if we have spaces like `" "` is to use `gsub` to replace those spaces to `""`

```
df[1:10] <- lapply(df[,c(1:10)], function(x) gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "", x))
```

and then change the `""` to `NA`

```
df[df == ""] <- NA
```

---

Or instead of doing the two replacements, we can do this one go and change the `class` with `type.convert`

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x)
      type.convert(replace(x, grepl("^\\s*$", trimws(x)), NA), as.is = TRUE))
```

NOTE: We don't have to specify the column index when all the columns are looped

Comment: Fantastic! Didn't know sapply created problems in the quotes. In addition, it is amazing the last solution `type.convert`. Great and thank you! @akrun

Comment: By the way, why you used `df[]` instead of `df` only in the last solution? @akrun

Comment: @user44049  If you notice the first two cases, it is `df[1:10]` i.e 1:10 inside the square brackets, ie. to we are subsetting the first 10 columns and updating those, similarly by using `[]`, it selects all the columns.  The reason for using `[]` is to give the output the same structure as in the original dataset, remember that `lapply` returns a `list`

Answer (score 4):

I just spent some time trying to determine a method usable in a pipe.

Here is my method:

```
df <- df %>% 
    dplyr::mutate_all(funs(sub("^\\s*$", NA, .)))
```

Hope this helps the next searcher.